# Recursión. Reproducción de bichos

Tags: c++, algoritmos, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

Necesito ayuda por favor para el siguiente programa en C++:

> ###### Descripción.
>
> Acabas de descubrir una nueva especie de bichos y estás estudiando su reproducción (la cual es asexual, es decir, no necesitan parejas para tener bebés). Al final de cada día ocurre lo siguiente:
>
> - Un bicho del tipo A produce como bebés a un bicho de tipo A, tres bichos de tipo B y un bicho de tipo C.
> - Un bicho del tipo B produce como bebés a dos bichos de tipo B y dos bichos de tipo C.
> - Un bicho del tipo C produce como bebés a un bicho de tipo A y cuatro bichos de tipo C.
>
> Los bebés maduran rápido y sus propios bebés nacerán al siguiente día de haber nacido ellos. Por si fuera poco, los bichos que ya tenías nunca morirán y seguirán teniendo bebés cada día. Si comienzas con N
> bichos de tipo A, ¿cuántos bichos tendrás en total después de D días?
>
> ###### Entrada
>
> Dos enteros N,D. Puedes suponer que N,D≥0.
>
> ###### Salida
>
> Un entero que sea el número total de bichos tras D días. Puedes suponer que el resultado cabe en un int.

Realicé mi código de la siguiente manera con una función recursiva:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int total_bichos(int N, int D) {
    // Inicializamos el número de bichos de cada tipo en el primer día
    int bichos_tipo_A = N;
    int bichos_tipo_B = 0;
    int bichos_tipo_C = 0;

    // Iteramos a través de los días
    for (int i = 0; i < D; ++i) {
        // Calculamos cuántos bichos de cada tipo se producirán en este día
        int nuevos_A = bichos_tipo_A + bichos_tipo_A * 3 + bichos_tipo_A * 1;
        int nuevos_B = bichos_tipo_B + bichos_tipo_B * 3 + bichos_tipo_B * 2;
        int nuevos_C = bichos_tipo_C + bichos_tipo_A * 1 + bichos_tipo_B * 2 + bichos_tipo_C * 4;

        // Actualizamos el número total de bichos de cada tipo
        bichos_tipo_A = nuevos_A;
        bichos_tipo_B = nuevos_B;
        bichos_tipo_C = nuevos_C;
    }

    // Calculamos el número total de bichos después de D días
    int total_bichos = bichos_tipo_A + bichos_tipo_B + bichos_tipo_C;
    return total_bichos;
}

int main() {
    // Pedimos al usuario que ingrese los valores de N y D
    int N, D;
    cin >> N >> D;

    // Calculamos y mostramos el número total de bichos después de D días
    cout << total_bichos(N, D) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

El error persisnte en que el programa genera resultados correctos para valores pequeños, pero resultados incorrectos para valores más grandes, ¿qué podría hacer para solucionar está cuestión?

Comment: Usar tipos numéricos más largos. Un int está limitado a `2147483647`. Un `unsigned int` está limitado al doble de eso (en vez de usar mitad del rango para negativos va de 0 al doble del anterior). Dependiendo de lo que necesites guardar tendrás que usar un tipo u otro, puedes verlos en la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Yo usaría un `float` o `double`, aunque sea a costa de precisión.

Comment: Chicos es muchisimo mas simple el problema.. primero, la funcion no es recursiva.. para nada.. despues, si bichos_tipo_B = 0; entonces, siempre es 0, porque la cuenta, da siempre 0.. lo mismo para C.. para mi, tenia que ser N, pero bue...

Comment: Creo que las líneas de A y B están mal. Debería ser `nuevos_A = 2 * bichos_tipo_A + bichos_tipo_C` y `nuevos_B = 3 *  bichos_tipo_B + 3 * bichos_tipo_A`.

Comment: A partir del día 12 los resultados exceden la capacidad de `int`. Esto sí sería recursión https://tio.run/##VY7dCoMwDIXv@xSB3dhOwR92o@KrjJp2W0FbsfVq7Nm7RhnMEDjJSfsluCzFEzHGi7E4bUpDb5wPq5bzwJixAYILcrqPBl/OZ2TIHEjGQ/AQZaTn8GaQwjwgox4GKPnuUKw6bKs942oh4UqIRoypaERi3wSmkvxapB07qICKd@yPQmP6gR37sOPOWRqb/U7wQbUtui1A359XVjmUe1Y1p@H@Uls1JVKMXw

Comment: Mateo muchas gracias, solo fue el razonamiento, todo lo demás estaba bien, te agradezco, era `nuevos_A = 2 * bichos_tipo_A + bichos_tipo_C y nuevos_B = 3 *  bichos_tipo_B + 3 * bichos_tipo_A`

Comment: La funcion no es recursiva... eso se entendio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como pudiste ver en los comentarios:

1. Tu función no es recursiva, en su lugar, utiliza un bucle for. Una función recursiva es aquella que se hace llamadas a si misma. Puedes buscar más información acerca de que es la recursividad en internet
2. El uso de int garantiza el uso de un mínimo de 15 bits para almacenar los números enteros (+1 para el signo), aunque en la mayoría de compiladores usará 31 bits. Esto son número hasta un máximo de 32.767 y 2.147.483.647 respectivamente. Para evitar que esto suceda demasiado pronto deberías usar un tipo de entero de 64 bits y deshacerte del signo para aprovechar los 64 bits y no perder uno en el signo. Esto te permite trabajar con números hasta 18.446.744.073.709.551.615
3. Tu código presenta fallos a la hora de calcular los nuevos bichos

Este sería tu código corregido:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

uint64_t total_bichos(int N, int D) {
    // Inicializamos el número de bichos de cada tipo en el primer día
    uint64_t bichos_tipo_A = N;
    uint64_t bichos_tipo_B = 0;
    uint64_t bichos_tipo_C = 0;

    // Iteramos a través de los días
    for (int i = 0; i < D; ++i) {
        // Calculamos cuántos bichos de cada tipo se producirán en este día
        uint64_t nuevos_A = bichos_tipo_A + bichos_tipo_A * 1 + bichos_tipo_C * 1;
        uint64_t nuevos_B = bichos_tipo_B + bichos_tipo_A * 3 + bichos_tipo_B * 2;
        uint64_t nuevos_C = bichos_tipo_C + bichos_tipo_A * 1 + bichos_tipo_B * 2 + bichos_tipo_C * 4;

        // Actualizamos el número total de bichos de cada tipo
        bichos_tipo_A = nuevos_A;
        bichos_tipo_B = nuevos_B;
        bichos_tipo_C = nuevos_C;
    }

    // Calculamos el número total de bichos después de D días
    uint64_t total_bichos = bichos_tipo_A + bichos_tipo_B + bichos_tipo_C;
    return total_bichos;
}

int main() {
    // Pedimos al usuario que ingrese los valores de N y D
    int N, D;
    cin >> N >> D;

    // Calculamos y mostramos el número total de bichos después de D días
    cout << total_bichos(N, D) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```